# How can I install plugin into CkEditor, Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I am using [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor). And now I need to add one new plugin. [This](http://ckeditor.com/forums/Plugins/HTML5-Video) 
I have read that, I should download and extract it into  "plugins" folder :

> Extract the contents of the file into the "plugins" folder of
>   CKEditor.

But I have not any "plugins" folder in my project. There is one, but it is located in `Lib\site-packages\ckeditor\static\ckeditor\ckeditor\plugin`.

So, if I add it there - it will be unavailable when I will deploy it in production or on another computer...

And what should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this thread](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/193)

> static files go into static files directory. If you put plugin ins a ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins subfolder it will work. Collectstatic will merge all files and folders and you will get typical ckeditor setup

So, put the plugin code in the `static` folder of your project, in `static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins` and it should work.

Comment: So, I have put package `video ` into `myproject\static\ckeditor\ckeditor\plugins\` then run `collectstatic` And Django has copied all CKEditor configs into package `creditor` and there, near to it  is package `static` in which exists my `video` plugin

Comment: And, when I add `'extraPlugins': ['video',]` to CKEDITOR_CONFIGS there is not any changes and my editor is not available now

Comment: Have you defined the STATIC_ROOT in your settings.py?

Comment: Yes, STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

Comment: It seems the setting is incorrect. The thing is - on dev server you don't need to run `collectstatic`, and then static files from your app(s) will be used. So, to see if ckeditor works (with the plugin) let it be served from your app `static` folder (and not from the STATIC_ROOT folder). To do that delete the files and folders generated by `collectstatic`.

Comment: I have delete this folder. But nothing changes. Here is some settings https://gist.github.com/Q-bart/ae9818bf8aae5f85eaa2

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949506/cant-get-ckeditor-plugins-to-work-in-django) maybe it helps you.

Answer (score 7):

Thank for your question. I just add `html5audio` plugin into `djnago-ckeditor`. Full path is:

1. Download plugin from the [official repo](http://ckeditor.com/addon/html5audio).
2. Unzip `html5audio` directory into `/path/to/your/project/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/` or `/python/libs/ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/` with all it's content.
3. Add `html5audio` plugin into your `settings.py` near other `CKEDITOR` variables:

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'extraPlugins': ','.join(
            [
               'html5audio',
            ]
        ),
    },
}
```

4. Reload page with ckeditor widget :).

Comment: Thanks. I will use it, when I need,

Comment: @Q-bart i glad if i can help. Few days ago sat down about 1.5 hours and try to make it work. At the end i think that full receipe of adding plugin will be usefull for someone else :).