# Load blockquote plugin in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I want to use CKEditor via [django-ckeditor](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor).

CKEditor gets loaded, but I fail to load the `blockquote` plugin.

- I downloaded `blockquote.zip`, unpacked it
- Copied it to my app like this `myapp/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/blockquote`
- I run `collectstatic`. I can access the blockquote/plugin.js file via browser if I inter the URL by hand.
- I updated the config:

  CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
      'default': {
          'extraPlugins': 'blockquote',
      }
  }
- The HTML contains the `blockquote`: `<textarea cols="40" id="id_body" name="body" rows="10" data-processed="0" data-config='... "extraPlugins": "blockquote", ...' data-external-plugin-resources='[]'`

But the plugin does not get loaded. I looked checked it with the firefox network debugger. These file gets loaded `ckeditor-init.js`, `ckeditor.js`, `config.js', but not a single file of`blockquote`.

Related issue: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/261

How to load the blockquote plugin in CKEditor?

**Update**
In the other question the author sees requests to "codesnippet/plugin.js". In my case I don't see any access to the plugin.js file of blockquote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get CKEditor plugins to work in django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26949506/cant-get-ckeditor-plugins-to-work-in-django)

Comment: @AnnaTomanek No, it is not a duplicate. The other question sees requests to "codesnippet/plugin.js". In my case I don't see access to the plugin.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use django_ckeditor and blockquote, but did not need to add it as an extra plugin. Are you sure you really need to do it that way? One thing that I'm thinking is the problem is that you define the extra plugin, but you don't put it in any of your toolbars. Perhaps it doesn't load if it's not defined in a toolbar. Have you tried updating your toolbars?

Here's my example config:

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
            ['Undo', 'Redo'],
            ['Scayt'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor'],
            ['Source'],
            ['Maximize'],
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'RemoveFormat'],
            ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Blockquote'],
        ],
        'toolbar': 'Basic',
    },
}
```

Comment: In my case I changed `basic` to `default` and it worked. Thank you

Comment: OK, it seems that you don't need the blockquote plugin at all. I don't get it. Why is the blockquote plugin needed at all, if it works without it?

Comment: @guettli I updated the example to remove future confusion.

I think the reason you don't need the blockquote plugin is that it's baked-in to the default ckeditor.js file included with django_ckeditor. You can customize what plugins are included in your own version of the ckeditor.js by using the ckeditor builder. http://ckeditor.com/builder

I still think that the plugin you added explicitly wasn't loaded because it wasn't referenced in your toolbars anywhere, but I haven't verified if this could be the case.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be in the default config of django_ckeditor: https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/blob/675d88e65b71e3ecf723605d6981846895f45faf/ckeditor/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/build-config.js#L57

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Django, so I apologize if this is off base.

Is the folder structure setup properly with ckeditor as a subfolder of ckeditor?

or should it be myapp/static/ckeditor/plugins/blockquote?

Comment: Yes, the folder structure is correct. The "ckeditor/ckeditor" looks like a typo but it is not. It's a way in django to make overwrites possible. But this does not matter much, since the client does not try to download the js files. I would be happy if I would see a file-not-found request to the blockquote/plugin.js file. That's something I could solve. But in my case the client does not load the plugin ...