# Add blockquote to djangocms-text-ckeditor

Tags: django, djangocms-text-ckeditor

Does anybody know how to add the HTML element `blockquote` to djangocms-text-ckeditor, so that a user can select from a dropdown as opposed to amending the HTML code directly?

I'm pretty sure that this is supported, as when I add the html:

```
<blockquote>Text goes here...</blockquote>
```

Directly to the source panel, it is formatted and displays nicely:

[image: Example block quote]

I've tried adding as a custom style in the settings as follows:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {            
    'stylesSet': [
        {'name': 'PullQuote', 'element': 'blockquote', 'styles': {'color': 'Blue'}}
    ],
}
```

But that doesn't work. I know the syntax is correct, as when I change the element to "h1" it works fine.

I'm not 100% how to amend the paragraph format dropdown, but it makes more sense that blockquote lives here, if possible.

Any help would be much appreciated.

## UPDATE

I've realised that I must have been misunderstanding what the `stylesSet` does. If I add the above settings, and then enter the html for `blockquote` manually, I can then select the style for this blockquote which turns it blue. This is not what I'm trying to do, but makes sense.

So I guess I'm looking to add the `blockquote` to the paragraph format. Now I'm not clear if that is supported, as when I try and add the following to my settings:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {    
    'format_tags': 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address;div;blockquote', 
}
```

That is, addding `blockquote` onto the end of the defaults, the editor fails to load completely. If I remove just the word `blockquote` then the editor works as expected.

It's a shame if that's the case, as I'm going to have to create a child plugin purely for adding the `blockquote`, which just seems overkill.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that to add this feature onto the default editor you have to update the configuration in your settings.py file.  [The documentation for django-ckeditor](https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=blockquote#example-ckeditor-configuration) is where I started.

**settings.py**

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar_CustomConfig': [
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                'Preview',
                'Maximize',
            ]},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format']},
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Blockquote']},
            {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Flash', 'Table', 'HorizontalRule', 'Smiley', 'SpecialChar']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'CustomConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        'tabSpaces': 4,
    }
}
```

This should be all the features of the regular bar plus blockquote (plus ordered and unordered lists).

Answer (score -1):

So I managed to solve my own question thanks to stumbling across this solution:

[Load blockquote plugin in CKEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36028699/load-blockquote-plugin-in-ckeditor)

I have to enable blockquote in the toolbar, which I've done using the below settings.

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {    
    'toolbar_CMS': [
        ['Undo', 'Redo'],
        ['cmsplugins', '-', 'ShowBlocks'],
        ['Format', 'Styles'],
        ['TextColor', 'BGColor', '-', 'PasteText', 'PasteFromWord'],
        ['Maximize', ''],
        '/',
        ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', '-', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat'],
        ['JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight'],
        ['HorizontalRule'],
        ['Link', 'Unlink'],
        ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-', 'Table', 'Blockquote'],
        ['Source'],
    ]
}
```